# SQL sort data based on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with an SQL problem. I'm not sure it's possible to do, but i have this table:
[image]

Obtained from this SQL statement:

```
SELECT distinct Account.Box, Account.Name, Account.Currency, Account.LastUpdated, Account.LastUpdatedBy, Transactions.Totals 
FROM Account
LEFT JOIN Transactions
ON Account.AccountGUID = Transactions.AccountGUID
```

What i would like to end up with is this result:
[image]

So basically comparing the Totals for each groups of Name or Currency, to obtain the highest Totals for each group. (NULL values are to be replaced by zeroes).

Comment: Do you need to compare totals for different update times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to just want a `group by`:

```
SELECT a.Box, a.Name, a.Currency, a.LastUpdated, a.LastUpdatedBy,
       MAX(t.Totals) as Totals
FROM Account a LEFT JOIN
     Transactions t
     ON a.AccountGUID = t.AccountGUID
GROUP BY a.Box, a.Name, a.Currency, a.LastUpdated, a.LastUpdatedBy;
```

Note:  I also added table aliases to make the query easier to understand.

Comment: I see no GROUP BY clause in your statement

Comment: @Martin . . . That would be an obvious oversight, given the comment.  It has been fixed.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following one ,hope you will get the result what you are expecting.

```
select * from 
(SELECT distinct Account.Box, Account.Name, Account.Currency, Account.LastUpdated, Account.LastUpdatedBy, Transactions.Totals as Totals
FROM Account
LEFT JOIN Transactions
ON Account.AccountGUID = Transactions.AccountGUID) as p 
where p.Totals = (select max(totals) from transactions)


group by Box, Name, Currency, LastUpdated, LastUpdatedBy ;
```

(or)

use the following one also

```
SELECT a.Box, a.Name, a.Currency, a.LastUpdated, a.LastUpdatedBy,
       MAX(t.Totals) as Totals
FROM Account a LEFT JOIN
     Transactions t
     ON a.AccountGUID = t.AccountGUID
GROUP BY a.Box, a.Name, a.Currency, a.LastUpdated, a.LastUpdatedBy;
```

Thanks.

Comment: for the second block, did you just copy Gordon's answer? Can you explain what is going on in the first query? Also please try and format your code with the text editor so that code blocks display as code blocks rather than text :)

Comment: the inner query gives the entire total records ,for that result set applying the where condition where the total has maximum with group by function.